# How can I download the raw metamodels from my EMF registry?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, metamodel

I'm using Eclipse EMF in a project with [MoDisco](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MoDisco) as a dependency.

I can access many different metamodels through the MoDisco Explorer, but I can only open them using the MoDisco browser. Is it possible to have access to the raw metamodels somehow? (all of them: Ecore files, XSD schemas, etc.)

I checked the MoDisco [source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/modisco/org.eclipse.modisco.git/tree/), but apparently, the metamodels are not stored there.

Example of what I want to do:

1. Open the MoDisco Explorer

[image: Screnshot of the Modisco Explorer with the "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Tree" selected]

2. Select some of the registered metamodels (e.g. http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Tree)
3. Open the raw file for this metamodel. I don't want to open the metamodel with any model explorer. Instead, I want access to the actual text (XML) file.

I know there are other ways to find the metamodels, but I am interested in this specific process. Is it possible?

The only similar question I found at SO is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165334/list-all-available-models-in-emf-application), but it's not the same problem.

Comment: I see some metamodels in the source code e.g. here: https://git.eclipse.org/c/modisco/org.eclipse.modisco.git/tree/org.eclipse.modisco.facet.custom.metamodel/model

Comment: Indeed, there are ecore models in the source code. Still, these are the metamodels used by the MoDisco tool, not those registered in the local environment during installation.

Comment: The registered ones shown in the screenshot are from different projects and can be found in the source code of those projects, e.g. [`http://www.eclipse.org/sirius/tree/1.0.0`](https://github.com/eclipse-sirius/sirius-desktop/blob/ceb41b85f8120516edf46412ea040d13fac4098f/plugins/org.eclipse.sirius.tree.model/model/tree.ecore#L3C76-L3C116)

Comment: @howlger In the screenshot, I filtered by the word tree, and it gave me this list. I'm not sure yet, but I bet the MoDisco Explorer presents all metamodels registered in the Eclipse Ecore register. However, they also register a bunch of metamodels during installation, so in the explorer, I have access to a lot of metamodels that are not related to my projects (access through MoDisco model browser, but not access to the original XML files, which generated my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to go programmatic about it. This does not seem too hard if you are familiar with the loading of EMF Resources.

I would create a dummy plugin that programmatically accesses the registry of metamodel that MoDisco shows (not sure if this registry is specific to MoDisco or just the EMF one). This should basically give you a list of URIs of all the metamodels available on your platform.

Then you can iterate on this list and for each URI, load the contents in a Resource which you then serialize into a local file or to the console.

Comment: You are right; I didn't even consider investigating the registry programmatically, but this is probably the only solution to get all metamodels from the registry (I guess they use a mix of local registry and some MoDisco metamodels that are registered during installation)